# Division sign(÷) and multiply sign(x) returns a weird character(Ã·)

Tags: java

I'm using the default Charset for Android which is **UTF-8**.
So when I send a division sign or a multiply sign, I get a weird character in return.
The character that was return is `.Ã· Ã—`

In the ASCII Table website, it is shown under the Extended ASCII Characters table.
As I'm using `.getBytes()`, I assume, I can't have more than 128 right?

The `Division Sign is 246 in decimal` and `0xC3 0XB7 in UTF-8 Hex`.

Is there a way to implement the division sign and multiply sign in? Or is there a way to bring out an error/popout message when a user inputs a division sign / multiply sign?

```
//Sending out the Data to the Bluetooth Device
outputStream.write(0);
msg.getBytes();
if(msg.getBytes().length > 0)
{
outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
}
```

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin


I don't have any code that can show the sign that I've got though. My code is basically just sending the bytes that I got from an editText.

Comment: The division sign ÷ U+00F7 (`"\u00F7"` as a Java string) would have a decimal value of 247. U+00F7 does form the byte sequence `C3 B7` in UTF-8.

Comment: @McDowell but when I use the Termite Terminal for sending data out using Bluetooth, it outputs .Ã· Ã—

Comment: According to these [Termite docs](http://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm) the tool supports obsolete Windows "ANSI" encodings and not UTF-8: _If you wish to send a non-ANSI/ASCII character, you need the "hexadecimal view" plug-in filter, see "Downloads" above._

Comment: @McDowell I'm using the Hexadecimal View and i get `0xc3 0xb7` which represents the real division sign.